# EntityType 'Category' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Developing a basic ASP.net MVC 4 application. Its a simple product catalog application, where in I have 2 database tables ('Category' and 'Products')

There is a foreign key reference of 'Category id' (primary key in Category table) in 'Products' table.

When I run the application, I am getting error message (listed below).

```
System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Category' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Category' is based on type 'Category' that has no keys defined
```

This looks like a common error for newbies,I did check all the related solutions to 'Entity key '' has no key defined.' but still my problem is not solved, Kindly help me in understanding this problem and what is the correct solution to this problem.

Below are my model classes

**Category.cs**

```
namespace ChemicalStore.Models
{
    public partial class Category
    {
        public int CatId { get; set; }
        public string CatName { get; set; }
        public string CatDescription { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }     
}
```

**Products.cs**

```
namespace ChemicalStore.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int CatId { get; set; }
        public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
        public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public string ProductPackage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. why is this question marked as duplicate of the later question?

Answer (score 79):

You should add attribute [Key] before property CatId:

```
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

        public partial class Category
        {
            [Key]
            public int CatId { get; set; }
            public string CatName { get; set; }
            public string CatDescription { get; set; }
            public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
        }
```

The problem is that EF can work only when it knows primary key of table. By default EF recognize as primary key property with name Id. If your table has another primary key, you can mark it with attribute [Key] or set Key with fluent configuration.

Comment: Totally agreed. By convention MVC will expect a property called "CategoryId", but you instead put "CatId", so you need to use data annotation and put [Key] for "CatId" to let MVC knows that is your primary key for the model Category.

Comment: Thank you so much I am a newbie and this saved me from further frustation.

Comment: I have the same error. But I verify that I respect convention my property is `public int AccountRoleId` Have you other ideas ?

Answer (score 13):

Entity Framework uses a primary key field to create the primary key column on the generated table.

It uses convention to get this column with some variations:

- If the field is called `id` or any casing variance;
- If the field is called `ClassNameId` of any casing variance;

I may be missing some more conventions, but these are the most common cases.

If you don't have any field with this conventions you need to mark your desired primary key with the attribute `[Key]`:

```
[Key]
public int CatId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 8):

I was able to solve this by adding a setter to my key property; I only had a getter before.

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: I found that the lack of getter/setters will fire this exception, too.  Have this in place along with the "Key" attribute

Comment: A `private set` is enough

Answer (score 7):

Just place [key] attribute on above id ..

```
[Table("employee")]

public class Employee
{ 

    [Key]

    public int Empno { set; get; }

    public string Empname { set; get; }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity classes are auto generated..

***Manual changes to those files will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.***

You need to create a partial class with all your metadata

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(Category.CategoryMetadata))]
    public partial class Category
    {
        internal sealed class CategoryMetadata
        {
            [Key]
            public int CatId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string CatName { get; set; }
            public string CatDescription { get; set; }
            public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Read more on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

Comment: The OP appears to be using the code-first approach.  So this answer does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are getting below error.
""One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Checking.Models.Employee: : EntityType 'Employee' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.""
just check your table column name and defined property name same or not .
if not then correct it proble resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed this problem adding the right connectionString in the web.config/app.config file.

I had forgotten adding it and the DBContext was not able to communicate with the DB.

Hope it helps