# Entity Framework - Relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am looking to create `Currency` and `CrossRates` in Entity Framework.

From a SQL perspective the `CrossRates` table would be quite simple.

```
Date      |FromCurrency|ToCurrency|Rate
01/01/2000|USD         |EUR       |1.5
01/01/2000|EUR         |USD       |0.67
```

**How do I take the above idea and apply it within Entity Framework?**

Here is what I have so far...

```
  public class Currency
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

    //navigation
     public virtual List<CrossRate> CrossRates { get; set; } 
   }

  public class CrossRate
  {
      public int FromCurrencyId {get;set;}
      public int ToCurrencyId {get;set;}
      public DateTime Date {get;set;}
      public decimal Rate {get;set;}

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create two one-to-many relationships, so `Currency` must have two collection of `CrossRate`. You can't have single collection referenced by two FKs, unless the PK of the another entity is composite (like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436731/composite-key-as-foreign-key)), but `Currency` only have one PK. Try with this model:

```
public class Currency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //navigation prop, these are the CrossRates where this Currency was used as a From
    public virtual ICollection<CrossRate> FromCrossRates { get; set; }

    //navigation prop, these are the CrossRates where this Currency was used as a To
    public virtual ICollection<CrossRate> ToCrossRates { get; set; }
}

public class CrossRate
{
    public int FromCurrencyId { get; set; }
    public int ToCurrencyId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public Currency FromCurrency { get; set; }

    public Currency ToCurrency { get; set; }
}
```

And the relationships configuration would be:

```
        //composite PKs of CroassRate entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<CrossRate>().HasKey(cr => new {cr.FromCurrencyId,   cr.ToCurrencyId});

        //one-to-many 
        modelBuilder.Entity<CrossRate>()
                    .HasRequired(s => s.FromCurrency)
                    .WithMany(s => s.FromCrossRates)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.FromCurrencyId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CrossRate>()
                   .HasRequired(s => s.ToCurrency)
                   .WithMany(s => s.ToCrossRates)
                   .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.ToCurrencyId });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override context's OnModelCreating() method to define relationships. See the tutorial [http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        //one-to-many 
        modelBuilder.Entity<CrossRate>()
                    .HasRequired<Currency>(s => s.FromCurrency)
                    .WithMany(s => s.CrossRates)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.FromCurrencyId );

        modelBuilder.Entity<CrossRate>()
                    .HasRequired<Currency>(s => s.ToCurrency)
                    .WithMany(s => s.CrossRates)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.ToCurrencyId );
}
```

You also should add

```
    public Currency ToCurrecy{get;set;}
    public Currency FromCurrecy{get;set;}
```

to your CrossRate class. For relationship, ICollection is better approach than List.

Comment: have added Currency to CrossRate class. However VS complainining about the s.Currency in ".HasRequired<CrossRate>(s => s.Currency)"

Comment: Seems better.However, VS now complains "EntityType 'CrossRate' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType"

Comment: [Key] attribute is required for primary keys. See the topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862013/entitytype-category-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype

Comment: Hmm on ToCurrencyId property?

Comment: Yes both ToCurrencyId and FromCurrencyId properties. I updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77895/discussion-between-mark-h-and-scokmen).

Comment: Unfortunately this was not the answer.