# VB entitytype has no key defined. define the key for this entitytype

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model-view-controller

I am asking for a solution for VB not C#. Hence the "VB" tag at the start of my question.

Trying to create a controller for my model, however, I keep getting "entitytype has no key defined. define the key for this entitytype". I am using VB MVC5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityType 'Category' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862013/entitytype-category-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype)

Comment: No, if you took the time to actually read the question, you would have seen that its for VB not C#.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to import dataannotations and dataannotations.schema to your model, compile it and then add your controller. Also, make certain that your class has a int property.