# Code First calling a stored procedure passing in 3 params validation errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I have been successful with calling a stored procedure when passing in just 1 parameter, but now with my code first dbcontext, I am wanting to keep it simple, but I altered the code based on some answer I seen  :/  not working

OK, first off here is code that does work:

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@dt", myTime);
var result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<QAList>("dbo.GetDateTime @datetime", param).ToList();
```

The above code works just fine, but this code here is not working (I'm passing in 3 params)

```
var paramPhone = validRequest.Phone;
var paramAccount = validRequest.AccountNumber;
var paramLead = validRequest.LeadId;

var result = _db.ValidRequests.SqlQuery(
    "dbo.CheckForValidRequest @Phone, @AccountNumber, @LeadId", paramPhone, paramAccount, paramLead);
```

Now I know that I am NOT using the same type of syntax `dbcontext.Database`,  but that was based on what I had read elsewhere.

I did set up a `DbSet`, so it is looking like this

```
 public DbSet<ValidRequest> ValidRequests { get; set; }
```

However, I did not do anythig in `OnModelCreating` with modelBuilder like I normally do with linq to SQL queries.

My error message:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> MyProject.ValidRequest: EntityType 'ValidRequest' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   ValidRequests: EntityType: EntitySet 'ValidRequests' is based on type 'ValidRequest' that has no keys defined

Normally I would define a key, but this is a stored procedure that I'm calling...

UPDATE : Trying a different way , but yes... it is jumping into onModelCreating

I was trying this approach

```
 using(var _db = new ClearviewContext())
   {
      var p = new SqlParameter("@Phone", paramPhone);
      var a = new SqlParameter("@AccountNumber", paramAccount);
      var l = new SqlParameter("@LeadId", paramLead);
      var r = _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec CheckForValidRequest @Phone, @AccountNumber, @LeadId", p, a, l); 
   }
```

That returns -1  when I should get a 0 based on the data I passed in :/

UPDATE 2  -  I added an OUPUT param and was spending too much time , I really want to figure out how to fix this, but for now sadly I resorted to going OLD SCHOOL  :(

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sprocName, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", paramPhone);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber",  paramAccount);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeadId", paramLead);
SqlParameter outParam = new SqlParameter();
outParam.ParameterName = "@clean";
outParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
outParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(outParam);

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
xt = outParam.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi, I think you should use [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) first.

Comment: You just need to define a primary key for your ValidRequest table, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862013/entitytype-category-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype

Comment: Well, even if this is the result of calling a stored procedure, the model class `ValidRequest` **must have** a primary key defined for it to be able to be used by Entity Framework. So basically, based on your fields in `ValidRequest`, you need to pick one or several that form a valid primary key (non-null, unique for each row of data) and decorate your `ValidRequest` C# class with `[Key]` annotations (or define the primary key in your `OnModelCreating`)

Comment: @marc_s  -  Ok  I did add a Key earlier, I will add it back again,   do I need a  dbset ?  do I need to do a  `modelBuilder...  MapToStoredProcedure` ?  thx

Answer (score 0):

in the early versions of EF,Entity model class was derived from Objectcontext
     but now it is derived from DbContext class which is a wrapper class for the ObjectContext class.

To call the Stored Procedure, we need the entity instance as of ObjectContext

```
 var context = (_entity as IobjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;//ObjectContext have ExecuteStoreQuery<T> as overloaded method and T denote the return type
```

1. **Stored Procedure without parameters:**
  a.  GetStatus – Name of Stored Procedure.
  b.  empty collection of object as Parameters.

```
var lst = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<tblStatu>("GetStatus", new string[] { });
```

2. **Stored Procedure with parameters:**
a.  GetMyName – Name of Stored Procedure.
b.  @FirstName, @LastName = Parameters.
c.  parameter -  collection of object as Parameters.

```
var parameter = new object[] {
                 new SqlParameter("@FirstName", "Vikas"),
                 new SqlParameter("@LastName", "Mahajan")
                };
Int32 recordID = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Int32>("GetMyName", @FirstName,@LastName, parameter).FirstOrDefault();
```

3. **Stored Procedure With complex Return Type**:
For Complex Return Type, we need to declare a Custom Class with the properties as of in the return dataset of stored procedure.
a. SvcRequestStatus(T) – Custom Class
b. GetStatusDynamixQuery - Name of Stored Procedures.
c. empty collection of object as Parameters.

```
IEnumerable<SvcRequestStatus> lst1 = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<SvcRequestStatus>("GetStatusDynamixQuery", new string[] { });
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: Can you explain a few things ?   like  _entity ,  do I replace _entity with my dbcontext  called `ClearviewContext`  or do I need to use an instance of it like I show in my code like `_db`   ?

Comment: Also,  Even if I replace @FirstName, @Lastname with my parameters, these are not in quotes,  I assume you meant  `"GetMyName, @FirstName, @LastName", parameter`    Otherwise VS .net complains

Comment: I do have an OUTPUT parameter, how can I also add that too?     Notice the working code I pasted it is called  `@clean`        thx

Comment: _entity ius my dbContext object,"@FirstName", "Vikas" its the key value pairs